# tcp connection between matlab and c

Tags: c, matlab, tcp

1.**Abstract:**
I  wrote a code  in C which is transfer a single character pressed on keyboard to matlab, and the matlab will receive it,  and print it. but the problem is that matlab does not response immediate, for example when I press "a" in the terminal the matlab should response immediate, but that does not happen. the matlab takes an amount of time (maybe ~10 to 15 seconds), and receive all the characters that pressed at that time as a one block and print it, 
 **2.Example:**
 if I entered in the terminal (C part) the letters : a b and c the matlab should print :

label =

a

label =

b

label =

c

but matlab print the following:

label =

abc
**3.Implementation**
  
 C code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0 , n = 0 ;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;   

    listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    listen(listenfd, 1);
            connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);        
static struct termios oldt, newt;

    /*tcgetattr gets the parameters of the current terminal
    STDIN_FILENO will tell tcgetattr that it should write the settings
    of stdin to oldt*/
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldt);
    /*now the settings will be copied*/
    newt = oldt;

    /*ICANON normally takes care that one line at a time will be processed
    that means it will return if it sees a "\n" or an EOF or an EOL*/
    newt.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON);          

    /*Those new settings will be set to STDIN
    TCSANOW tells tcsetattr to change attributes immediately. */
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newt);

    /*This is your part:
    I choose 'e' to end input. Notice that EOF is also turned off
    in the non-canonical mode*/
    char character_old = getchar();

    while((character_old != '.'))
    {   


    char character_new = getchar();



    if ( ( write(connfd, &character_new, sizeof(char))) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n ERROR IN WRITE \n") ;
    }
    character_old = character_new ;
    printf("character \n : %c\n",character_old);
    }   
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldt);
close(connfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Matlab code:

```
function [l label]  = test()
l = tcpip('127.0.0.1' , 5000) ;
l.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'byte' ;
l.BytesAvailableFcnCount =1;
fopen(l);
x = 1 ; 
while (x==1)
        label = fscanf(l , '%c');
        label 
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you expect `fscanf` to read always one char or do you expect it to read it in the same chunks you send it in c?

Comment: @Daniel I expect it to read always one char, and that's what I want to do

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your previous question? There you wanted to read 46 values now you want to read 1 value. Just change the numbers.

Comment: @Daniel my idea is to label those 46 values, so this communication must be synchronous with the 46 values tcp connection, i.e for each 46 values , matlab read the character(label) which is send in the same moment, I expect if i do the same, it will buffer the data, and I will receive the previous label character. The user who label the data will not be able to send the character immadiate with the event, which specify the new label, and will just always press the buttons.